# Google Token Authentication missing type payload

Tags: android

I am trying to verify authorization token provided by google through a java project. I have followed Tim Bray's article "Verifying back-end calls from Android apps". I downloaded google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc. But my java project does not run and either says "Could not find main Class" or gives "You are referencing a missing type Payload." Can anybody please tell what might be wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the zip file, the google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar contains the required Payload class, you have to add this jar to your verifyer project's path.

Read more about setting up google-api-java-client here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup